# Setting Date and Time Variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a MySQL select statement to get all data out of a MySQL table *(events)* for the current day that a visitor is seeing the page. However, by current day - I mean between 6AM and 5:59AM the next day. The reason being that events last till early morning the next day, I want the page to show events that are still taking place when a person views the website - at 1AM for example.

I have this code so far

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE %DATE_START_SELECTED% <= start_datetime AND end_datetime < %DATE_END_SELECTED%
```

However I'm baffled as to how I'd set the %DATE_START_SELECTED% and %DATE_END_SELECTED% in php. Any Ideas please :)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE %DATE_START_SELECTED% between to_date(start_datetime AND end_datetime)
```

Comment: Hi NarayaN, sorry I am a little inexperienced in this :), what is the *to_date8 variable? And I still have to set %DATE_START_SELECTED% to the current day don't I? And if the person is viewing the page early in the morning before 6AM, I would have to set it to the previous day then

Comment: 1. *to_date* is not a variable.It is used to convert strings to date format in mysql like start_datetime and end_datetime. 2nd thing is yes you have to set %DATE_START_SELECTED% to the current day.....No if the person is viewing page early in the morning then u dont have to worry for yesterdays date....let it be todays date.........I hope i am clear enough......Write for more queries.

Answer (score 1):

Can you solve your problem with this simple sql statement?

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE start_datetime >=  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
AND end_datetime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  + INTERVAL  24*60*60-1 SECOND)
```

Comment: Hey Marek, thanks for your answer, I will try this right away. But before I test it, because I'm new can I ask you something? The Unix timestamp will get the current server date? The location I will be using is different from where the server is located. Is there an alterative?